# What is the best format exporting a list of coordinates from Mathematica to Matlab?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, export, coordinates

I have been lucky to avoid Matlab for a longtime now. However I need to export for my colleague such a list which is ,are of 384 list of 8 disks coordinate and radius.

What type of Export Format would be a convenient for her to draw those back from Matlab ?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Export` can export to [Matlab's .mat](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/MAT.html) files (version 4). I suppose your colleague should be able to import those.

Matlab also [imports text files](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/importdata.html) and some [spreadsheet formats](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/import_export/f5-100860.html). Therefore, Mathematica's export in the [CSV](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/CSV.html), [TSV](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/TSV.html) and [XLS](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/XLS.html) formats should work as well.

Comment: @mr.wizard thanks, but still 70 to go. It will take a couple of weeks.

Comment: I shall endeavor to make it sooner than that. :-D